# What is the difference between "container" and "provided" in SBT dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

When reading `build.sbt` of many web applications, one can often see dependencies marked as `"provided"`, see e.g. [sbt-assembly documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly):

> "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "0.8.0-incubating" % "provided"

I was unable to find any mention in SBT documentation, however [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) says following about provided:

> - provided
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime

Sometimes however I have also seen `"container"` in the same position, like in [this build.sbt](https://github.com/magicdrive/sbt-tomcat-templete/blob/master/build.sbt). Is this the same thing?

```
val tomcatVersion = "7.0.53"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.tomcat.embed" % "tomcat-embed-core"         % tomcatVersion % "container",
  "org.apache.tomcat.embed" % "tomcat-embed-logging-juli" % tomcatVersion % "container",
  "org.apache.tomcat.embed" % "tomcat-embed-jasper"       % tomcatVersion % "container",
  "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-catalina" % tomcatVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.tomcat" % "tomcat-coyote"   % tomcatVersion % "provided"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That forth element of the dependency associates the dependency with a *configuration*; establishing a [*configuration dependency*](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Per-configuration+dependencies).  It originates with [*ivy*](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/tutorial/conf.html), which `sbt` uses internally.

The *"container" configuration* is defined by
[`xsbt-web-plugin` version 0.9](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/docs/0.9.md#quick-reference), which is brought into the project you reference [here](https://github.com/magicdrive/sbt-tomcat-templete/blob/master/project/plugin.sbt).
It is being used to establish the container/hosting runtime for `sbt container:start`.

As an aside - that runtime would necessarily provide the runtime libraries corresponding to the *"provided" configuration*, which were used during the compile phase but not included in the transitive dependencies for the resulting artifacts.